# Where to find hard instances of subsetsum and other famous np-complete problems for testing heuristics against?

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, online-resources

[Can move to cs or tcs stackexchange if thats a better home]

I remember back around 2016 DIMACS used to host a list of problem instances of various famous problems in the NP-complete class and harder classes. Usually "problem instance data", "solution" and sorted by difficulty for testing new algorithms/heuristics against.

After quite a bit of googling I couldn't find that page so I was curious where one can find known "hard" instances to play around with.

Do any research groups still host such files? (The DIMACS data was nice because it included very easy to very difficult instances and the entire range between).

Comment: For those that stumble upon this, https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/datasets.html also has some nice stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the DIMACS Implementation Challenges page:
http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/programs/challenge/